# aurelia multiple viewPorts on the same component

Tags: viewport, router, aurelia

Is it possible to use viewPorts with the same component, without it being instantiated twice. E.g.

```
 config.map([
        {
            route: 'route1',
            name: 'route1',
            viewPorts: {
                default: {moduleId: './route1-module'},
                heading: {moduleId: './route1-module', view: './route1-module-heading.html'}
            },
            nav: true,
            title: 'Route1'

        }]);
```

**route1-module** is been instantiated and attached twice. I need to avoid it.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? You have two viewports... how do you share the same component between two viewports? Do you just want the same backing VM and the same view?

Comment: I want one backing component having two views, that I can attach in different parts on parent view.

Comment: So essentially you want placeholders where two bits of content are rendered but you want one single viewmodel to back it? Something like MVC partial pages or ASP.NET master pages?

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about ASP.NET. but yes, you describe exactly what I want

Comment: Something like this? https://gist.run/?id=677f5ca6a20b315a10d77d224be2cebb - (you may need to resize the right hand example pane to see the menu - the menu button doesn't work) - this loads the same module but uses a "layout" master view which the content is projected into using content selectors. This has been upgraded to slots for shadow DOM v1 and will probably be present in the next release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the layouts feature that will be present in a later release (I'm not sure when but the PR has been merged recently).

The PR is here: https://github.com/aurelia/templating-router/pull/25

Essentially it gives you a chance to specify a view/viewmodel pair (a **layout**) that will sit in place of the original module when routed to. Instead the original content will be projected into the layout using `slots`.

**Example:**

*route-config*

```
config.map([
    { layoutView: "layout.html", moduleId: 'page1' }
]);
```

*page1.html*

```
<template>
    <div slot="slot1">some content</div>
    <div slot="slot2">some other content</div>
</template>
```

*layout.html*

```
<template>
    <div class="some-fancy-container">
        <p>This is slot 2</p>
        <!-- slot2 content will be projected here -->
        <slot name="slot2">some fallback content</slot>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <p>This is slot 1</p>
        <!-- slot1 content will be projected here -->
        <slot name="slot1">some fallback content</slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Resulting HTML output:

```
<template>
    <div class="some-fancy-container">
        <p>This is slot 2</p>
        some other content
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <p>This is slot 1</p>
        some content
    </div>
</template>
```

This is similar to MVC partials or ASP.NET master pages and allows you to specify an alternative layout for certain pages (without needing child routes).

It's very distinct from viewports (it also works with viewports in that you can specify a layout for a viewport too)